# sms to mobile through javamail api

Tags: java, sms, jakarta-mail

How do I send sms to mobile through javamail api?

And is it necessary to know j2Me for sending sms through java?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I send sms to mobile through javamail api?

JavaMail is for sending email, not SMS. However, if you can find an email-to-SMS gateway service such services do exist), then that might work for you.

> And is it necessary to know j2Me for sending sms through java?

No.